# Play custom bundled sound in apple script

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

So im trying to use shellscript "afplay " in applescript to play an .m4a file I bundled into the app resource. Not entirely sure how it works.

Got this after a bit of searching around,

```
set soundPath to POSIX path of (path to resource "Sound File.aiff")

do shell script "afplay " & quoted form of soundPath
```

This isnt really what I want.

Comment: What do you *really* want?

Comment: Assuming "Sound File.aiff" is located in the Application bundle's Resource folder, then the two lines of code will indeed play the sound. You said "This isnt really what I want." without stating what is is you want!

Comment: well.. I just need something that will play a sound I bundled into the script, but I'm too dumb :(

Answer (score 0):

```
playAudio() -- place this Line To call the handler to Play An Audio File.    

on playAudio()
    set audioFile to path to resource "Sound File.aiff"
    set theFile to POSIX path of audioFile
    do shell script "afplay  -q 1 -t 25 " & " " & quoted form of theFile
end playAudio



-- Command Line OPTIONS For Playing Audio Files
(*
afplay [option...] audio_file

Options: (may appear before or after arguments)
  {-v | --volume} VOLUME
    set the volume for playback of the file
  {-h | --help}
    print help
  { --leaks}
    run leaks analysis
  {-t | --time} TIME
    play for TIME seconds
  {-r | --rate} RATE
    play at playback rate
  {-q | --rQuality} QUALITY
    set the quality used for rate-scaled playback (default is 0 - low quality, 1 - high quality)
  {-d | --debug}
    debug print output
*)
```

Comment: Thanks! but how do i set the path to the sound I bundled into the app?

Comment: If the sound file is in the resources folder of your app bundle.. That's what this line of code is pointing to..  Just change theActual filename to whatever it will be.  'set audioFile to path to resource "Sound File.aiff"'